# Manipulate strings inserted via array functions in Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

If I have the following query:

```
=IFERROR(split('New Accounts'!A2,"~"),"")
```

I get a row of the following values (but in difference cells without commas):

```
CHO9999958, 12/14/2015, 14:33:16,   11, 3461,   5888,   18.41511913,    -33.92568992,
```

I want to remove 'CHO' from the 1st value, ideally I would like to do this without creating another sheet.

Is this possible?

Comment: thank you for the helpful comment in response to downvoting the answer... This gives me a great clue as to how to either a. ask a better question, or b. close it if it really is a dumb question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always the first 3 characters that you want to remove from the output then this formula might work:

`=IFERROR(split(RIGHT('New Accounts'!A2,LEN('New Accounts'!A2)-3),"~"),"")`

Comment: Thanks that will do the trick. I'm hoping (for future reference) to be able to work with individual strings after the split - iteratively. I feel like this should be possible...